# Automatic image upload and display in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, upload

How to make the browser upload and display image after the user puts it in the file upload widget? I've got a form where an image should be uploaded and edited by the user on the fly (before they hit submit). Can I do it with Jquery?

Comment: Here is an advanced example of the jquery image upload. [jquery-gallery-image-upload-with-sorting](http://www.webwavers.com/blog/jquery-gallery-image-upload-with-sorting/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the JQuery [MultiFileUpload plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/MultiFile/).

Answer (score 1):

MultiFileUpload plugin should give you what you're looking for. It's important to remember that ajax does not support transferring binary files - you'll need an embedded IFrame to do the work for you.